# Javascript accordion tabs close

Tags: javascript, tabs, dom-events

I use an accordion that I want to continue to build. I would like to close all open tabs if I select another tab so that only one tab is open. I am very new to Javascript and am trying to get it right.

Here is my js code:

```
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (panel.style.maxHeight){
      panel.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: So I assume you code is not working? Could you please post the whole code? For example in https://jsfiddle.net

Comment: the tabs open on click and close again .. I want to close the open tabs when another tab is open .. only one tab should remain open thants what i want thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

*the tabs open on click and close again .. I want to close the open tabs when another tab is open .. only one tab should remain open thants what i want thanks :) – Mr.Murphy*

Okay... although I don't know for sure it's that but it looks like:

```
acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (panel.style.maxHeight){
        panel.style.maxHeight = null;
        } else {
        panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
    }
```

});

You are adding the `onclick` to your accordion **but** then you are using `this` which should close your currently clicked element. Instead you should create an array and append all opened tabs to it, then close them when a new one opens.

Hope it helps, Elias =)